# Why does XmlNode to XmlElement works in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

This is something I noticed looking at while working with some of our old vb code.
This line will not throw any kind of cast exception...

```
Dim moduleElement As XmlElement = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/modules/module")
```

But this line will in C#...

```
XmlElement focusFieldsNode =  moduleNode.SelectSingleNode("ui/initial_focus_fields");
```

Now to resolve this I cast as an XmlElement, but why would that work in vb and not in C#?

Comment: VB does all kinds of implicit casts for you - do you have Option Strict On in the VB code?

Comment: A cast makes sense since you are assigning a base class instance to a derived class variable. VB wants to help you do whatever you want to do, even when it's questionable.

Comment: This is the reason people pick c# over VB (although, there are stoic vb defenders.) c# will stop you doing bad things in design time while vb is more lax at design and you will get errors later in runtime. If you would get a tool like Resharper, your VB code would be underscored and it would say "possible runtime error"

Comment: Why? Because you have the [strict compiler setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) set to `novice` aka. `off`. Set this to `on` and VS will highlight the line: *"Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'System.Xml.XmlNode' to 'System.Xml.XmlElement'"*

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at where they are from:

> [XmlNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> [XmlElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> [XmlLinkedNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmllinkednode(v=vs.110).aspx)

The `XmlElement` inherits from `XmlLinkedNode` which inherits from `XmlNode`.

So they are from the same type. Casting will provide you with the extra functionality that comes from the specific derived class.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that the casting *is* happening in the VB code, it's just that VB is doing it for you with Option Strict Off. In C# or in VB with Option Strict On, you need to have the cast in order to compile.

Comment: That makes sense.  I forgot about the strict option.